# javascript height math recalc on every page change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ive got a javascript calculating the height of a iframe element and the document height. Then use a if to see if the iframe element is on or off. When its off the height is 1px and display is none. When its on the height is 34px and display is block. I do all this with another function that is irrelevant to this question. The question is why when I change pages if the height is less then the previous page it dosen't recalculate the height and set it correctly, BUT if the height is bigger then the previous page it does recalculate and sets the height acordingly. Im using a onload="javascript:autoHeight" on the body tag of every page so that it recalls the function every time the diferent page loads and only when its done loading so it gets the height correctly. If you need more code: http://alomadruga.com.br/temp/home.php

```
function autoHeight(){
var docHeight = $(document).height();
var radioHeight = parent.$("#radioiframe").height();
if (radioHeight == 34){
    parent.$('#content').css({'height': docHeight + 34+ 'px'});
    alert("radio iframe is on");
}
else {
    parent.$('#content').css({'height': docHeight+ 'px'});
    alert("radio iframe is off");
}
};
```

Thanks for every ones help but I managed to figure it out on my own and decided I would post the answer to help whoever comes by this question. What i did is that every time it runs the function I set the height to 1px first then let it run the function.

```
function autoHeight(){
    parent.$('#content').css({'height': 1+ 'px'});
var docHeight = $(document).height();
var radioHeight = parent.$("#radioiframe").height();
if (radioHeight == 34){
    parent.$('#content').css({'height': docHeight + 34+ 'px'});
    alert("radio iframe is on");
}
else {
    parent.$('#content').css({'height': docHeight+ 'px'});
    alert("radio iframe is off");
}
};
```

Comment: What web browsers are you seeing this behavior in? All of them? Some of them?

Comment: all of the main browsers

Comment: This part of the code looks very unusual: `parent.$("#radioiframe").height()`.  If this is jQuery, I can't imagine what this is doing?  Do you perhaps mean `$("#radioiframe").parent().height()`?

Comment: @jfriend00: He's using an `iframe`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.parent

Comment: im quite sure its correct because its working and setting the height. What that does is it sets the height of the content iframe on the parent page.

Comment: I guess I'm not used to leaving the `window` off.  I always write `window.parent` rather than just `parent` which is technically the same, but seems more clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to apply this CSS:

```
html {height:100%}

body {
    margin:0; padding:0;
    height:auto !important;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: thanks but that didn't solve my problem because the javascript overwrites the css with inline css defining the height automaticly.

Comment: this css giving to you right height of the body even then the content height < user view port height

Comment: yeah but it still didn't solve my problem the javascript is getting the correct height on the pages but when the page height is smaller then the previous page height it dosen't set the smaller height and just leaves a big empty after the footer